# Unity3D: I want my moving 3D objects to have a consistent shading

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, shading

I have 2 directional lights in the scene, light 1 is parallel to the Y axis (I want it to make a shadow underneath the sphere), light 2 is parallel to the x axis.

I have some barriers(3d cube objects) that are moving to the left side of the screen( velocity = (-20,0,0) ).

**I want the barriers to have a consistent color/shade while moving through the scene**.  When the object is on the right side of the screen it is darker and as it moves to the left, right before it moves off the screen, it gets brighter.  I can't figure out why!

**What I've done:**

I found if I remove all lights from the scene the effect doesn't happen.

I've removed all other objects from the scene.

In the lighting options I've turned off RealtimeGI and Baked GI.
I've removed the Skybox and turned Ambient Intensity, Reflection Intensity to 0.

Here is the effect to help understand it more:

[Barrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qca3v.png)

[Barrier moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6zAh.png)

Thanks if you can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it had more to do with the orthogonal camera.  I noticed that if I move the camera source point further away, the effect disappeared.  My guess is the angle of my camera and how close it was to my main scene intensified the color so it showed it as brighter.

That is my guess anyways,  If someone has a better answer please let me know!